# Is there a website to generate short stories from prompts?

Tags: creative-writing, short-story

Is there a website that can take prompts/context & create short stories?

Comment: Do you mean automated story generation (e.g. based on GPT-3)?

Comment: I dont have a clear idea about GPT 3. But from what I know, is that not too adnavced? I was looking for something that can genrate simple text. But yes, I mean automated story generation.

Comment: Is GPT 3 free. I'll try to check it once.

Comment: You can experiment with [GPT-3 for free for a bit](https://openai.com/api/pricing/) (you get $18 free credit that's valid for 3 months). I'm not sure how suitable it is for writing short stories, though (getting a proper narrative structure is probably not trivial). But it's worth a try.

Comment: Is AI reliable, and can be used to write stories?

Comment: Will check GPT-3. But what you say is true too, maybe this won't suit my requirements. I'll try it once though.

Comment: In my opinion, AI is not entirely reliable. I'm planning to use it just to get ideas. Or when I'm stuck at any point. Personally, I want to use it as an aid, not entirely depend on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Random detail generation, or the green fairy:

Having someone else's idea for a story is no good. Why would you want to have an AI write random stories for you? I'm sure you can find someone willing to write you random stories if that is really what you want. Or [this site](https://www.plot-generator.org.uk/story/) is one I simply Googled randomly. [THIS](https://blog.reedsy.com/plot-generator/) one generates a plot for you. BORING! They aren't clever, or good.

The Writing Stack Exchange  is more about the creative process, not random junk. ***But*** sometimes random junk is fun.

If you simply have a few random details that you then need to build a story around, that can be a fun way to get a story rolling quickly. But those ideas can come from ANYWHERE. Just pick something.

Stephen King had started to write a story as a kid, wrote a line, and stopped (as it was told to me). As an adult, he found or remembered the line, and it became the genesis of the Gunslinger series of books. Or the recent writing challenge for the stack exchange was to write a mute character. These small seeds are like a crystal dropped in a solution that allows a story to come together around a tiny start.

But I wouldn't bother with a website for this. Almost anything random can be the genesis for a story. I turned on the TV and flipped from a vampire movie to a documentary about deep sea exploration and had the genesis for a story of a lesbian oceanographer vampire retreating to an ocean habitat to keep away from people (and she didn't need to worry about oxygen or pressure...) and falling in love with a dying octopus watching over her eggs that were about to hatch. Another time, I picked up the dictionary and started looking for words I hadn't heard of. So make a story where a character needs to make an abatis (a barrier of fallen trees) while drinking absinth (a once popular spirit known as "the green fairy" thought to stimulate creativity, currently making a comeback).

If it HAS to be a website, then use a random website generator. There are any number of such generators. I picked [THIS](https://random-ize.com/random-website/) one - you guessed it - Randomly. But in three clicks, I landed on a page transposing random images (in this case, a kitty background and a shark), a page about the world beard and moustache championships, and a page where people can submit funny things that happen in their life.

So write a funny story about a huge-moustache-wearing man trying to feed a cat he hates to a shark. I can feel it coming together - his girlfriend hated his moustache and moved out of their houseboat, leaving the cat that just won't go away. Oh, maybe it's a black cat. Maybe it's an evil, cursed black cat. I think the guy is going to fall in the ocean. Does the shark eat him? Does he come to like the cat and rescue it from the shark?

Good luck!

Comment: That's an interesting perspective. I've already commented above. This is when I don't get ideas. Or want more improvement on my content. Its a really good thing how you get so many ideas. I dont sadly. I'm watching & reading to work on it. Will also try the things that you mentioned. I liked the dictionary idea. Also, appreciate how you mentioned about Stephen King. Took a long break & it's getting hard for me to get back. So needed some help. That was the only intention. And I'm writing for myself. So I hope I can improve this way.

Comment: "The Writing Stack Exchange is more about the creative process, not random junk. But sometimes random junk is fun." Can you elaborate on that? Like is my question not apt for the platform?

Comment: @MouseNag Okay, I was being a bit snarky. My answer was a bit tongue-in-cheek.  I upvoted the question, but just don't personally care for the computer-generated stories (even as a creative stimulator). Really, whatever helps with ideas is okay. They just tend to lead to formulaic thinking. If you want to be published, following the formula isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Late November 2022 OpenAI came out with very advanced chatbot called [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/). It is free for the moment, but probably won't remain so.

While creative writing is not necessarily its strong suit, it does have the ability to write short stories based on a prompt. It can also generate suggestions to continue a story, or fix grammar, and many other tasks. It is good enough at general writing to have caused worries about it being used by students to [write essays for them](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2022/12/chatgpt-ai-writing-college-student-essays/672371/).

Because it's designed as a chatbot there is a lot of flexibility in how you can interact with it. It keeps track of the chat history (up to ~ 4000 words iirc), so you can even ask it to elaborate on, or modify earlier responses or prompts.

Here's an example of some prompts and responses:

> **Prompt:**
> write a funny story about a huge-moustache-wearing man trying to feed a cat he hates to a shark
>
> **Response:**
> Once there was a huge-moustache-wearing man named Hank who absolutely hated cats.
> He hated them so much, in fact, that he would do anything to get rid of
> them.
>
> One day, Hank had the brilliant idea to feed his neighbor's pesky cat
> to a shark. He figured that if he could just get the cat to the beach,
> he could find a shark and toss the cat in.
>
> Hank put on his best moustache-wax and set off to catch the cat. It
> wasn't easy, as the cat was quite nimble and kept dodging Hank's
> grasp. But Hank was determined, and he eventually managed to catch the
> cat and stuff it into a beach bag.
>
> As Hank made his way to the beach, the cat started to meow and scratch
> at the bag, trying to escape. Hank was getting more and more
> frustrated, but he was determined to see his plan through.
>
> Finally, Hank arrived at the beach and began searching for a shark. He
> walked up and down the shore, looking for any sign of a fin or a tail.
> But no matter how hard he looked, he couldn't find a single shark.
>
> Just as Hank was about to give up, he heard a loud roar behind him. He
> turned around to see a massive great white shark charging towards him,
> its teeth bared and its eyes trained on the beach bag.
>
> Hank panicked and threw the bag as hard as he could, hoping to get rid
> of the cat once and for all. But as the bag flew through the air, the
> cat managed to wriggle free and land on the beach, safe and sound.
>
> Hank, on the other hand, was not so lucky. The shark gobbled him up in
> one bite, and all that was left of him was his huge moustache, which
> floated gently on the waves.
>
> And so, the pesky cat lived happily ever after, while Hank's hatred
> for felines was finally put to rest.
>
> **Prompt:**
> Change Hank to Peter and replace the shark with a giant octopus. Put it to rhyme.
>
> **Response:**
> There once was a man named Peter
> Whose moustache was thicker than ever
> He hated cats, it was true
> And he knew just what he had to do
>
> He set off to catch one, determined and brave
> But the cat was quick and Peter couldn't catch it, he raved
> He tried and he tried, but the cat always got away
> Until finally, Peter had had his fill of this cat play
>
> He grabbed the feline and stuffed it in a bag
> And set off to the beach, where he planned to brag
> To his friends about the giant octopus
> That he'd use to rid himself of this fuss
>
> He searched and he searched, but no octopus could he find
> He was getting frustrated, he was losing his mind
> Just when he thought all hope was lost
> He heard a loud cry and he turned to see, oh what a cost
>
> A giant octopus was charging his way
> Its tentacles writhing, it wanted to play
> Peter panicked, he didn't want to be caught
> So he grabbed the bag and threw it with all his thought
>
> The octopus lunged, but it was too late
> The cat had escaped and landed on the plate
> Peter, on the other hand, was not so lucky
> The octopus caught him, and his fate was mucky
>
> All that was left was Peter's huge moustache
> Floating on the waves, it looked quite posh
> The cat lived happily, free from harm
> While Peter's hatred for felines came to an end, alarm

The rhyming doesn't always work, but it's a pretty decent effort for a machine that has no idea what it's doing.